# getWindowHandles return one window handle if multiple tabs are open in single window

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, window-handles

`getWindowHandles` returns incorrect value in firefox browser. When I opened multiple tabs in a single firefox window and tried to find out the number of window handles to check weather it's returning correct value, getWindowHandles still returns value as single window. If I open the tab in new separate window, getWindowHandles return correct value.
Is this a bug?

I tried the same with chrome and I.E its working as expected.
Firefox version: 37
Selenium version: 2.45
OS: Mac and Windows

I have already tried the code refer the code in attachment.

Comment: link for code https://docs.google.com/document/d/17SEJE5WeGL1mv0HJtYqQbw9ZMUN-KuXBrsS4KW79Uh0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended according to the FirefoxDriver team. See their response at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1614:

> In the case of clicking on a link that opens a new window (via target=_blank or a similar mechanism, the driver will know about those windows or tabs. The case of attempting to control+click (or command+click) a link to open it in a new tab circumvents the driver's mechanism for creating new top-level browsing contexts. Thus, such new tabs or windows are not managed by the driver.