# Selenium driver.WindowHandles return just one ignoring tabs on Firefox - Cant navigate between multiple tabs

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, tabs, webdriver

Selenium driver.WindowHandles return just one handle ignoring tabs on Firefox.
Cant navigate between multiple tabs.
See code below.
I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427390/selenium-getting-data-from-another-tab-instead-of-active-one/34427979#34427979) problem and the response solved it, but my question wasnt precise, then im asking again.
The response helped me but now im stuck on the problem of this question, a problem that another person had too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874788/getwindowhandles-return-one-window-handle-if-multiple-tabs-are-open-in-single-wi) but without answers.
There is another having it even with separate window but in chrome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450384/does-selenium-chromedriver-currently-have-support-for-handling-pop-up-windows).

```
//-------------------------------------------------
        public static void testab()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/ncr");
            IWebElement elmTxt = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#lst-ib"));
            elmTxt.SendKeys("google" + Keys.Enter);
            IWebElement elmQtdRes = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#resultStats"));
            string strWebStat = elmQtdRes.Text;
            IWebElement elmNewsLnk = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href*='tbm=nws']"));
            elmNewsLnk.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Return);
            IWebElement elmBdy = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body"));
            elmBdy.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "2");
            //-------------------------------------------------
            driver = switchLastOpenedTab(driver); // works
            elmQtdRes = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#resultStats"));
            string strNewStatV1 = elmQtdRes.Text;
            Console.WriteLine("Stat for NEWS(V1):[" + strNewStatV1 + "]");
            Console.WriteLine("Stat for WEB:[" + strWebStat + "]");
            //-------------------------------------------------
            driver = switchTabByIndex(driver, 2);  // throw an Exception
            elmQtdRes = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#resultStats"));
            string strNewStatV2 = elmQtdRes.Text;
            Console.WriteLine("Stat for NEWS(V2):[" + strNewStatV2 + "]");
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------
        public static IWebDriver switchTabByIndex(IWebDriver driver, int tabIndex){
            // it dont get a list of tabs just the windows container
            List<String> winTabs = new List<String>(driver.WindowHandles);
            int idx = tabIndex - 1;
            // because of comment above count here equal one
            if (idx >= winTabs.Count) {
                throw new Exception("This method dont work!!");
            }
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(winTabs[idx]);
            return driver;
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------
        public static IWebDriver switchLastOpenedTab(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            // it works but cant handle more than one new tab, cant navigate
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
            return driver;
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------
```